Can LibreOffice Base expand a subform record with a click on the main record
MS Access allows a subform in datasheet view to appear by clicking on the + to the left of the main form record. Can Libreoffice base do this? Can we get similar functionality somehow?
I know some folks actually like painting a separate table grid for each level, but when I have three levels of parent / child / grandchild related tables the MS user interface is, I think, much better. It's the main thing stopping me from ditching Microsoft for LibreOffice.

Thanks for your time & help.
